# Overlaying a rotated image in opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to overlay an image on top of a background after rotating it which works but because I used a region of image to place the overlay after rotating it the corners of where the overlay was are left out

```
pointer = rotatePointer(pointer, point2, point1, pointerNo)

rows, cols, channels = pointer.shape
x = int(point2[0])
y = int(point2[1])

roi = background[int(y - (rows/2)):int(y + (rows / 2)), int(x - (cols/2)):int(x + (cols/2)) ]

# Create a mask of pointer as well as it's inverse'
foreGrey = cv2.cvtColor(pointer,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(foreGrey, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
inverseMask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

#Black out area of pointer in roi
backgroundBlackOut = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = inverseMask)


#Take the pointer without alpha channel
pointerForeground = cv2.bitwise_and(pointer,pointer, mask = mask)
cv2.imshow('Mask', pointerForeground)
#Put the pointer into the ROI
dst = cv2.add(backgroundBlackOut, pointerForeground)
background[int(y - (rows/2)):int(y + (rows / 2)), int(x - (cols/2)):int(x + (cols/2)) ] = dst
return background
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Since the rotated image isn't a rectangle whenever it is overlayed onto the background it leaves blank space instead of what should be there in the background

Comment: Seems like you know what's wrong. What's your question?

Comment: I can see the issue when I output it, my question is can a region of an image be a rotated rectangle or is it stuck to be a rectangle in opencv, if I can change the shape of it how?